# how to keep an element in current state after animation is finished

Tags: css, animation

starting position of the element is - outside of viewport
a css animation should start after 2sec
when finished - the element is inside the viewport - but how to keep it in the current state ?
in the example below `abc` should stay  visible having `top:54px`

```css
.abc{
  position:fixed;
  top:-100%;
  width:25px;
  height:54px;
  background:orange;
  animation-name:animaa;
  animation-delay:2s;
  animation-duration:2s;
}

@keyframes animaa{
  0% {top:-100%;}
  100% {top:54px;}
}
```

```html
<div class='abc'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animation-fill-mode` property specifies a style for the element when the animation is not playing (before it starts, after it ends, or both).

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. For example,

```
.abc{
  ...
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```